# Angular SSR: ngAfterViewInit being called on server side, instead of client side

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular17, angular17-ssr

In my server-rendered Angular application using Angular 17, I have encountered a peculiar issue with the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. The problem arises when calling an `init` function within `ngAfterViewInit` that depends on an API request requiring a valid access token, which is only available in the client's local storage.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```js
async init() {
  await this.loadData();
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.init();
}
```

In this scenario, **when the application is run via SSR, the page doesn't render, and the application keeps loading indefinitely**. It seems that the **init function is being executed on the server side**, where the access token is not available, causing continuous retries without rendering any HTML.

However, if I introduce a delay using window.setTimeout, like the following:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.init();
  }, 2000);
}
```

The page loads successfully because the init function is executed on the client side, where the access token is available.

**Questions:**

**Why** is **ngAfterViewInit** being **called** **on** the **server** side in the first case, **contrary** **to** its **intended** **behavior** of **being** **called** on the **client** side after the view is initialized?

Note that, I am not using angular universal. Instead, I am using the built in SSR of angular 17

Answer (score 3):

Angular lifecycle hooks are run of both the server side and the client side.

You're probably looking for the `afterNextRender()` hooks which is only run on the client side :

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   afterNextRender(() => this.init(););
}
```